# Replacing several app into one in app store

Tags: app-store, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, itunes-store

My customer previously distributed commercial Apps A, B, C, D into app store sometime ago which several has bought installed. Now they changed their mind and decided to create one container App 'X' in which A,B,C and D are included and now as in-app purchase items. In future through this app they will add more apps like 'E','F' etc.

Assuming Apple approves this container app, i would like to understand how below scenario will work.

I can 'Remove' A,B,C and D 'from sale' so that it no longer shows in app store.

Per apple a non-consumable purchased item should be there to download any number of times under the account in which it was purchased

If i am an user who already purchased A,B,C and D and now also purchasing 'X', and if i delete A,B will it be available again to download even if it is not currently available in app store (due to my 'Remove from sale')?

Whether Re-releasing as container app is recommended or not, that is what customer is ordering us to do.

I would like to know how above scenario will work. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i am an user who already purchased A,B,C and D and now also purchasing 'X', and if i delete A,B will it be available again to download even if it is not currently available in app store (due to my 'Remove from sale')?

**Ans :** No it will not be available for further download.

For iCloud Stuff, iCloud manage only your account purchase info. Actual downloading is done from Apple Store only.

```
Your purchased content is automatically downloaded from the iTunes Store, App Store, or   iBookstore based on iTunes in the Cloud availability by country.
```

Refer this [iCloud: Restore your iOS device from iCloud](http://support.apple.com/kb/ph12521)

I dont recommend to release container app because user who had already purchased the app they again have to spent money to unlock the In-App which is not good. But if your customers are fine with that then your choice.

One Suggestion, Instead of re-releasing the container application you can assign URL Schema for each application so that user can go other application directly from one application if it fines with you.